# How to scroll to a certain point after clicking a link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I have a link on my page that when clicked uses .$get and then append to load content into a div#top-main-content. After this content is loaded I want the page to scroll down to the content that was loaded into #top-main-content. How can I achieve this?

```
  $(document).ready(function()
                          {

                              $('a.newsflash1').click(function() 
                                {
$('html,body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: '+=' + $('#scrollTo').offset().top + 'px'
                                    }, 'fast');
                                    $('#top-main-content').empty();

                                    $.get('index.xml', function(c){

                                    $(c).find('news_story').each(function(){

                                        var $story = $(this); 
                                        var storyTitle = $story.find("story_title").text();
                                        var storyCompany = $story.find("story_company").text();
                                        var storyAuthor = $story.find("story_author").text();
                                        var storyYear = $story.find("story_date").attr("year");
                                        var storyMonth = $story.find("story_date").attr("month");
                                        var storyDay = $story.find("story_date").attr("day");
                                        var description = $story.find('story_content').text();

                                        var html = '<div class="story-content darkborder">';
                                        html += '<div class="story-contrast lightborder">';
                                        html += '<h3 class="story-title">' + storyTitle + '</h3>';
                                        html += '<div class="story-copyright">';
                                            html += '<p class="story-company">'+ storyCompany +'</p>';
                                            html += '<p class="story-author">'+ storyAuthor +'</p>';
                                            html += '<p class="story-date">'+ storyYear+'.'+storyMonth+'.'+storyDay +'</p>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                        html += '<p class="story-body">' +  description + '</p>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';


                                        $('#top-main-content').append($(html));

                                        window.location.hash = '#top-main-content';

                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
```

Okay I have figured it out with the below code :

`$('html,body').animate({
                                    scrollTop: '+=' + $('#scrollTo').offset().top + 'px'
                                    }, 'fast');`

I've also fixed my code above so that you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.location.hash = '#top-main-content';
```

Or try this [`scrollTo` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: do I attach this to a click function?

Comment: do this in the get success function

Comment: what is the get success function?

Comment: `$('#top-main-content').append($(html));
         
         window.location.hash = '#top-main-content';`

Comment: It bounces the screen and then goes back to the top? It does not work. I can see the #top-main-content flash in the url for a sec and then disappear.

Comment: you must have something else redirecting the page

Comment: I've added some stuff to the original question so that you can see the code.

Comment: just added, sorry for the delay.

Comment: put `window.location.hash = '#top-main-content';` outside that whole `each` loop

Comment: Maybe their is a way to delay the trigger from scrolling down?

Comment: does it matter that I am viewing a file locally and not on the server?

Comment: You got it Neal, Thanx again.